# Parse: Recall data from the cache

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, caching, parse-platform

I Need a solution for the following:

Parse is running my query and stores everything within its cache via kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork.
Of all the data stored i only need 3 / 10 bits of information for the initial UITableView layout.
When I select a row i then need to be able to recall the remaining 7 bits of information in relation to the indexPath.row press.

Is there a way I can perform a query based on the indexPath.row against the local Parse cache to grab the remaining information?

Comment: How would you query the local cache? I don't really know what your intentions are but what if you store the first 3 returned objects in an array and the remaining in a different array you can pass to the VC. Or string or date or whatever you have

Comment: Thanks soulshined, I completely forgot about NSArrays!